# Limit Number Of Lines (or Rows) in Textarea

Tags: angularjs, textarea

I've seen some examples in jQuery and JS about this.

http://jsfiddle.net/XNCkH/17/

I've been looking around and I can see that you can limit the length (see fiddle). I was wondering if there was a way to limit the number of rows or lines in AngularJS or if character length is the way to go?

http://jsfiddle.net/7nxy4sxx/

```
<textarea ng-model="test" ng-trim="false" maxlength="1500"></textarea>
```

Thanks!
T

Answer (score 5):

Here is a working directive I came up with, using the new `ngModel.$validators` pipeline in the AngularJS 1.3 branch:

```
/*
maxlines attribute directive, specify on a <textarea> to validate the number
of lines entered is less than the specified value.

Optional attributes:
   maxlines-prevent-enter: Specify as false to NOT block the pressing of the Enter
    key once the max number of lines has been reached.
*/

app.directive('maxlines', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
      var maxLines = 1;
      attrs.$observe('maxlines', function(val) {
        maxLines = parseInt(val);
      });
      ngModel.$validators.maxlines = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        var numLines = (modelValue || '').split("\n").length;
        return numLines <= maxLines;
      };
      attrs.$observe('maxlinesPreventEnter', function(preventEnter) {
        // if attribute value starts with 'f', treat as false. Everything else is true
        preventEnter = (preventEnter || '').toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf('f') !== 0;
        if (preventEnter) {
          addKeypress();
        } else {
          removeKeypress();
        }
      });

      function addKeypress() {
        elem.on('keypress', function(event) {
          // test if adding a newline would cause the validator to fail
          if (event.keyCode == 13 && !ngModel.$validators.maxlines(ngModel.$modelValue + '\n', ngModel.$viewValue + '\n')) {
            event.preventDefault();
          }
        });
      }

      function removeKeypress() {
        elem.off('.maxlines');
      }

      scope.$on('$destroy', removeKeypress);
    }
  };
});
```

[Working Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/3wcblG?p=preview)

**NB:** This does not restrict the number of lines if the user pastes in a value with more than the allowed number of lines, but it will correctly flag the field as invalid.

Comment: How can you display the number of lines entered if the limit has been exceeded?

Comment: @RazvanB. You would need to extend the directive to add some markup after the input which you would update manually as part of the validator's functionality to show the number of lines count.